# SQL: get all pairs and triples from single column and count their frequences over another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

A simple table of `user_id, item_id` (both `text` data) on input.

The question is: what is the way to extract all pairs and triples combinations from `item_id` column and count their frequences over `user_id` (i.e. 1% percent of all users have (1, 2) `item_id` pair)

I've tried some barbarism:

```
select FirstID, SecondID, count(user_id)
from
(
SELECT 
    t1.item_id as FirstID,
    t2.item_id as SecondID

FROM
(
    SELECT item_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY item_id) as Inc
    FROM t1
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY item_id)-1 as Inc
    FROM t1
) t2 ON t2.Inc = t1.Inc
) t3 join upg_log on t3.FirstID = upg_log.item_id and t3.SecondID = upg_log.item_id
group by FirstID, SecondID
```

but got nothing

Comment: Please provide `INSERT` of sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular task belongs to the type which is easier to write than to execute:

```
declare @t table (
    UserId int not null,
    ItemId int not null
);

insert into @t
values
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 1),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 4);

-- Pairs
select t1.ItemId as [Item1], t2.ItemId as [Item2], count(*) as [UserCount]
from @t t1
    inner join @t t2 on t1.UserId = t2.UserId and t1.ItemId < t2.ItemId
group by t1.ItemId, t2.ItemId
order by UserCount desc, t1.ItemId, t2.ItemId;
```

As you can see, there is a semi-Cartesian (triangular) join here, which means that performance will drop quickly with the number of records growing. And, of course, proper indices will be crucial for this kind of query.

In theory, you can easily extend this approach to identify triples, but it might prove to be unfeasible on your actual data. Ideally, such things should be calculated using per-row approach, and results cached.